# why does my Fibonacci code outcome change with changing the condition like below?

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
def fib(limit):
    a, b = 0, 1

    while a < limit:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

x = fib(100)
for value in x:
    print(value, end="  ")
```

if you change the condition like below the outcome is not Fibonacci. Why?

```
def fib(limit):
    a = 0
    b = 1

    while a < limit:
        yield a
        a = b
        b = a + b
x = fib(100)
for value in x:
    print(value, end="  ")
```

Comment: I don't understand. You seem to be confused about why changing the code causes the output to be different, and seem to think that the output should be the same. Why do you think it should be the same?

Comment: You want the new `b` to be based on the old `a`.  The second snippet doesn't do that.

Comment: The statement ` a, b = b, a + b` is not equivalent to `a = b; b = a + b`. Do you not see the difference? Hint: your second formulation changes the order in which the LHS and RHS assignment and evaluation occurs. This can be a subtle distinction but in this instance is fairly obvious.